# Eclipse cdt, sorting src implementation based on the class interface C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

If I have a class like:

```
//sample.h
class A {
public:
   void method1();
   void method2();
};
```

and the implementation is like:

```
//sample.cc
void A::method2() {...}
void A::method1() {...}
```

Is there a way/shortcut to sort the implementations following the declarion in the class? (in the class declaration the order is method1, method2, while in the src the order is inverted).

Answer (score 0):

There is no current way to do this.

Feature requests are welcome and can be filed in [CDT's bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT).